# UIButton list event types

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, selector

I want to copy the actions of my UIButton to another UIButton. Now getting the required target and action has succeeded. But now I want also want to list the control events the UIButton has.

I found this field:

> [myButton allControlEvents]

but I am not sure how to get all events from it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182860/how-to-get-uibutton-target-action-and-control-events

Comment: This question is not a duplicate, the given duplicate only states the allControlEvents field. Not how to read it.