# How do i find the current delegate?

Tags: ios, xcode, uisplitviewcontroller

I am working on an app with a splitview controller and support for all orientations. But a button I added onto the detailview is not working when in landscape mode so I wondered how one can find out what the current delegate is, so that I can send a command for the action there.

*Update*

Basically the button(in the detailVC) is supposed to change the VC in the masterVC? Maybe not basic but it shouldn't be crazy difficult to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5183349/1083921 This will give you the actions and targets of your button.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get UIButton Target, Action and Control events?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182860/how-to-get-uibutton-target-action-and-control-events)

Comment: No see this is inherited code where the delgates and View Controllers have been split up and I am never sure how to find out which is which so I am looking for a way to find(log) the delegate as it is a highly complex app with a lot of different commands going off at any one time.

Answer (score 0):

If your asking for orientation case then

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

if(orientation == 0) //Default orientation 
  //UI is in Default (Portrait) -- this is really a just a failsafe. 
else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
  //Do something if the orientation is in Portrait
else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
  // Do something if Left
else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
  //Do something if right
```

Else case , I would like to know more about your question in detail(what exact delegate your looking for)

Comment: Well I'm trying to find out the name of the delegate as I want to add a method to it but there are a whole bunch so I wondered if there was a way to log it?

Comment: So this way you will get the orientation and depending on orientation you could program your operation(of your button in detail VC).

Comment: Yes I have something like this running in the AppDelegate, but thanks for trying.

Comment: So did you found solution to it? or was my info useful?

Comment: I found a solution to my problem but not too my question, and no unfortunately your info was not useful/relevant to either. I assume english is not your first language, but thank-you for trying bud.